# Drawing an image under the cursor while dragging

Tags: c#, windows-8, drag-and-drop, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

What is the easiest way to show the dragged item (image) under the cursor while doing drag-and-drop (C#, WinRT)?

It is easy to do with Adorners in WPF, but this feature is not available in WinRT applications.

The effect should be the same as when you drag an image in the Firefox browser.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the scenario a little more. at least for those who are not familiar with Adorners in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Popup and put whatever you would in AdornerLayer in WPF - in the Popup. Alternatively put a Panel somewhere that would be on top of your workspace and put the content in there. Setting IsHitTestVisible on your custom adorner layer would make sense too.

Comment: I used an image on the top of my grid (with opacity set to 0.5). I also set a WriteableBitmap as a source of that image and now I manipulate that bitmap to draw the image being dragged. Although this is not a perfect solution as the image will not be drawn outside my grid, but this is enough for my needs. Thanks.